# Efficient method to evaluate the following series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2\cdot (n+1)^2}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, factorial

How do I calculate the infinite series:

$$\frac{1^2\cdot 2^2}{1!}+\frac{2^2\cdot 3^2}{2!}+\dots \quad?$$
I tried to find the nth term $t_n$. $$t_n=\frac{n^2\cdot (n+1)^2}{n!}.$$
So, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}t_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^4}{n!}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}$$
after expanding. But I do not know what to do next.

Thanks.

Comment: One approach, not necessarily best, is to cancel n, then split remaining n as (n-1)+1 and cancel n-1, and keep going (paying attention to the beginning of the series). You get some integers and some e.

Comment: We can write $$ n^2(n+1)^2 = an + bn(n-1) + cn(n-1)(n-2) + dn(n-1)(n-2)(n-3). $$ Comparing coefficients yields $$a = 4, \quad b = 14, \quad c = 8, \quad d = 1.$$ Then the rest is clear, yielding $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{n!} = (a+b+c+d)e = 27e. $$

Comment: Look up [Dobiński's Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DobinskisFormula.html).

Comment: @sos440 I like your method much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, now you need to expand them separately and express each of them in form of $e$:

$$ \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}= \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+(n-1)n}{n!} =  \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{(n-1)!} +\frac 1{(n-2)!} = 2e $$

Similarly, we can show that,

$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{n!}= \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+(n^2-1)n}{n!} = 5e$$

and,

$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^4}{n!}= 15e$$

Comment: thanks.I like this method.

Answer (score 2):

Given that $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, we have
$$P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom xk\Delta^kP(0)$$
which is [Newton's series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Newton.27s_series). Therefore
\begin{align}
\sum_{m\ge0}\frac{P(m)}{m!}&=\sum_{m\ge0}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\Delta^kP(0)}{k!(m-k)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\Delta^kP(0)}{k!}\sum_{m\ge k}\frac1{(m-k)!}\\
&=e\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\Delta^kP(0)}{k!}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The forms of the power series, you reached in the last step of your work, are known as Bell numbers. Bell numbers are defined as:

$$ B_{m} = \frac{1}{e}\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^m}{n!} $$.

So your result can be written in terms of Bell numbers:

$$ e( B_{4} + 2\,B_{3} + B_{2})\,, $$

where $ B_{4}=15 \,, B_{3}=5\,,  B_{2}=2\,. $ See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

Answer (score 0):

$$ t_n = \frac{4}{n!} \left( \frac{n(n+1)} {2} \right)^2 $$

Comment: tn = (4/n!)[n(n+1)/2]^2