# Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{(k-1)!}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{(k-1)!}$

I sense the answer has some connection with $e$, but I don't know how it is. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You can use Bell numbers. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172231/efficient-method-to-evaluate-the-following-series/172255#172255).

Comment: The proposed duplicate does indeed provide an answer, provided the series is rewritten $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^3}{k!}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most elementary calculation is probably this one:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{(k+1)^2}{k!}&=1+\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{k^2+2k+1}{k!}\\
&=\color{red}{1}+\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{k}{(k-1)!}+2\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1{(k-1)!}+\color{red}{\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1{k!}}\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{k-1+1}{(k-1)!}+2\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac1{k!}+\color{red}{\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac1{k!}}\\
&=\color{blue}{1}+\sum_{k\ge 2}\frac1{(k-2)!}+\color{blue}{\sum_{k\ge 2}\frac1{(k-1)!}}+3\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac1{k!}\\
&=\color{blue}{\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac1{k!}}+4\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac1{k!}\\
&=5\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac1{k!}\\
&=5e\;.
\end{align*}$$

One can also make use of the identity $$x^n=\sum_k{n\brace k}x^{\underline k}\;,$$ where ${n\brace k}$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and $x^{\underline k}\triangleq x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-k+1)$ is a [falling power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol). In particular,

$$\begin{align*}
k^3&=\sum_{k=0}^3{3\brace i}k^i\\
&=0\cdot k^{\underline 0}+1\cdot k^{\underline 1}+3\cdot k^{\underline 2}+1\cdot k^{\underline 3}\\
&=k+3k(k-1)+k(k-1)(k-2)\;,
\end{align*}$$

whence

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{k^2}{(k-1)!}&=\frac{k^3}{k!}=\frac{k+3k(k-1)+k(k-1)(k-2)}{k!}\\
&=\frac1{(k-1)!}+\frac3{(k-2)!}+\frac1{(k-3)!}\;,
\end{align*}$$

and summing over $k$ yields $5e$ as before.

Answer (score 18):

Let's start with $e^x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$ then :
$$x\,e^x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(k-1)!}$$
$$x(x\,e^x)'=x\,e^x+x^2\,e^x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k\,x^k}{(k-1)!}$$
$$x(x(x\,e^x)')'=x(e^x+3x\,e^x+x^2\,e^x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2\,x^k}{(k-1)!}$$
Set $x=1$ to get : $$5\,e=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{(k-1)!}$$

Comment: Very nice, this way seems the most clear to me.

Comment: Thanks @littleO ! The trick of using the [theta operator](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ThetaOperator.html) $\theta=x\frac d{dx}$ works pretty often (two times here).

Comment: Very Nice! Very Nice! Magic trick.

Comment: Thanks @Babak [generating functions tricks](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) are indeed very nice!

Comment: Excellent! Very insightful.

Answer (score 3):

For $\frac{P(n)}{(n-r)!},$ where $P(n)$ is a polynomial.

If the degree of $P(n)$ is $m>0,$ we can write $P(n)=A_0+A_1(n-r)+A_2(n-r)(n-r-1)+\cdots+A_m(n-r)(n-r-1)\cdots\{(n-r)-(m-1)\}$

Here $k^2=C+B(k-1)+A(k-1)(k-2)$

Putting $k=1$  in the above identity, $C=1$

$k=2,B+C=4\implies B=3$

$k=0\implies 2A-B+C=0,2A=B-C=3-1\implies A=1$

or comparing the coefficients of $k^2,A=1$

So, $$\frac{k^2}{(k-1)!}=\frac{(k-1)(k-2)+3(k-1)+1}{(k-1)!}=\frac1{(k-3)!}+\frac3{(k-2)!}+\frac1{(k-1)!}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{(k-1)!}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \left(\frac{(k-1)(k-2)+3(k-1)+1}{(k-1)!}\right)$$
$$=\sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac1{(k-3)!}+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac3{(k-2)!}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{(k-1)!}$$ as $\frac1 {(-r)!}=0$ for $r>0$

$=e+3e+e=5e$

Comment: How do you think to create the first line?

Comment: @jasoncube, this is the de facto way of solving $\frac{P(n)}{(n-r)!}$ where $P(n)$ is a polynomial of $n$. Here the highest power of $n$ is $2,$ so, there will be $2+1=3$ constants.

Comment: Exactly the way I approached this.

Answer (score 2):

I have provided a proof of the general case [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44113/whats-the-value-of-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frack2k/44131#44131).  The proof provided shows

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^n}{k!} = T_n \cdot e
$$

where $n$ is the $n^{th}$ [Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).  Yours is the case $n = 3$.  Just for completeness, the formula above is called [Dobinski's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski%27s_formula).

Answer (score 2):

Let's finish it in one line

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k-2)(k-1)+3(k-1)+1}{(k-1)!}=5e$$

Chris.

Comment: How is this done?